# Authenticate IAM user with JSON file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there a way to generate `JSON` key file for `IAM` user and use it to authenticate `gcloud` CLI with it?

I know I can do it with `Service Account` but I was wondering if it can be done for IAM user account as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't as both gcloud or console don't provide you a method for this, and you should not try either. What you are trying to do is "Publishing your google account password".

To authorize as user, please use `gcloud auth application-default login`. While this is still not recommended by Google for elsewhere application, as it will warn you every time that you should switch to service account. As stated in [here](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/gcloud-auth.html).

> If you’re running your application elsewhere, you should download a
>   service account JSON keyfile and point to it using an environment
>   variable

If there is necessarily requiring a high-authority account. Create a service account as **Editor** or even **Owner**. So lets say some one get your json key, what he can access is just this project, but not the whole world of your user account.

Comment: I need that account to be able to create projects. I can't seem to do that if it is a service account.

Comment: @Asdfg , then you should use `auth login`. Create projects require credit card information, if there is a way someone can use your credit card by a simple json file. It will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) command in the CLI to login with a specific IAM user account with its credentials. For instance:

```
gcloud auth login <your email>
```